# Centering the Activity Indicator Portrait & Landscape Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Currently working under IOS 7, using the code below I was able to center the activity indicator in my rootviewcontroller both landscape and portrait. However the notification won't fire in either my addviewcontroller or indeed my detailviewcontroller for the same project. I want to be able to center the activity indicator in my addviewcontroller and detailviewcontroller as I did for the rootviewcontroller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//Configure and show the window
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

//Applications are expected to have root view controller at the end of application launch
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

return YES;
}
```

The following code illustrates how I set up my Activity Indicator in my rootviewcontroller, addviewcontroller and detailviewcontroller in the ViewdidLoad

```
 //Setup Activity Indicator.
self.activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];
self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.activityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.35, 1.35);
[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
```

The following code is what I use to center the Activity Indicator which I call in my ViewDidLoad in my rootviewcontroller.

```
//Make sure the activity indicator is centered both in landscape and portrait
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {
   if (activityIndicator) {
       activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    }
 }
```

Any assistance much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try to give individual frame for both portrait and landscape mode.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

 activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];

if(isPortraitMode)
            [activityView setFrame:CGRectMake(147.5,227.5,25,25)];
        else
            [activityView setFrame:CGRectMake(227.5,147.5,25,25)];

[self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Answer (score 1):

spinner.center = self.view.center;

Answer (score 0):

I think better place to handle rotation events is viewDidLayoutSubviews method, not notification centre.
I would add this this to every controllers where you want to centre it:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2,self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
}
```

Comment: Yes Greg this is the approach I am currently trying at the moment, and it works. however when I rotate from Portrait to Landscape it does not seem to recenter the activity indicator as it does implementing the notification approach for my rootviewcontroller above.

Comment: -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
} This solution worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);// if you want whole screen center then used :[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
```

Happy Coding...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {    
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center; 
}
```

Try this one for portrait